# How can I combine these two if statements?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

Here're two if statements I have (using Python):

```
if eval0 < eval1 and (theta/pi)%4 < 2:
    gamma *= (-1)
elif eval0 > eval1 and (theta/pi + 2)%4 < 2:
    gamma *= (-1)
```

I'm trying to shorten the code, so one way I can think of is

```
if (eval0 < eval1 and (theta/pi)%4 < 2) or (eval0 > eval1 and (theta/pi + 2)%4 < 2):
    gamma *= (-1)
```

Is there a better way I can do that? Thanks!!

Comment: What you have looks good to me.  Your goal is to write code so that when you come back and look at it in a year, it's clear what you intended.

Comment: Pre-calculating `theta/pi` value will shorten it a tiny bit.

Comment: if (eval0 != eval1) and ((theta/pi)%4 < 2 or (theta/pi + 2)%4 < 2):....

Answer (score 1):

Your latter block of code is perfectly fine:

```py
if (eval0 < eval1 and (theta/pi)%4 < 2) or (eval0 > eval1 and (theta/pi + 2)%4 < 2):
    gamma *= (-1)
```

The conditions are dependent and unique, and cannot really be simplified any further.

Answer (score 1):

```
if eval0 < eval1 and (theta/pi)%4 < 2 or eval0 > eval1 and (theta/pi + 2)%4 < 2:
    gamma *= (-1)
```